# Batch display of Tab spacing

Tags: batch-file

Im making a batch game, and made a "email" screen which looked like this

```
echo - INBOX (1)        -
echo - OUTBOX           -
echo - SPAM (3)         -
```

If I use TAB for spacing, the batch display is different than if I use spaces 
(if I use Spaces, the batch file displays it looking like it does in notepad)

Why is this?

(Screenshot: http://db.tt/z4NGvhUz - Top is with Spaces, bottom is with tab)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you post screenshots, maybe?

Comment: @adarshr sure, ill do that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TAB is one character that, when it is displayed in the screen, it is expanded to the next 8-character tabulation position. A text that contains Tabs is shown differently depending on the text that appears before the first Tab. Spaces are always spaces and are always shown in the same way.